# Under the hood difference between running a program in cmd prompt versus Windows explorer

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

I am facing a bit of strange issue that is: if I run an executable in the command prompt, in its path, it takes 7 seconds to open the first (logon) dialog.
If I run the same program in the same directory by selecting it in the Windows explorer and hitting enter (or double clicking it), it takes 6 seconds to do the same thing (open the first logon dialog).
On a slower system this gets more impacting.
Is there a difference in the application loading and execution process among explorer and cmd prompt? What this would be? If nothing can be done to improve the cmd response time, at least I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: It may depend on what's cached: on your second test, files and directories may remain cached from the first test. You need to alternate the tests several times before you can make firm conclusions.

Comment: Additionally if the program loaded shared objects into RAM on the first run, they would already be there waiting for the second run.

Comment: Hi Frank. In order to avoid this possible issue, I already did the tests more than once and the results remain. Running on Explorer always get the thing up faster than on command prompt (running in administrator mode).